# how to get all the different elements with max quantity from a list of objects in java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, max

I have a list of item.

```
class Item {
  private String name;
  private int quantity;

}
```

The List contains items like

```
List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
itemList.add(new Item("Item1", 5));
itemList.add(new Item("Item2", 10));
itemList.add(new Item("Item3", 10));
itemList.add(new Item("Item4", 7));
itemList.add(new Item("Item1", 15));
itemList.add(new Item("Item2", 16));
```

The output will be a list of items with max quantity like list of Item("Item1", 15), Item("Item2", 16), Item("Item3", 10), Item("Item4", 7).

I tried but not getting the exact result.

```
List<Item> maxQuantityItems = itemList.stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getQuantity() == maxQuantity)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Item::getName))));
```

Comment: Your Question is not completely clear about wanting to examine subgroups of objects that share the same value in the `name` field.  Rewrite to be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You want to collect your items into a Map, which will automatically resolve conflicts and provide a lambda function to reduce the values into your requirements: here, the highest quantity. The code should look like this:

```
List<Item> maxItems = itemList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Item::getName,
        Function.identity(),
        (item1, item2) -> item1.getQuantity() >= item2.getQuantity() ? item1 : item2
    )).values();
```

The `.values()` extracts the List (from the Map) for all highest quantity items.

Comment: An established convention is do keep the first element in case of a tie, i.e., to use `>=` instead of `>`. That’s what you also get when using `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt( Item::getQuantity))` as merge function.

Answer (score 1):

[`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is your friend:

```java
public static Iterator<Item> sortByQuantityDesc(List<Item> items) {
    Queue<Item> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Item::getQuantity).reversed());
    queue.addAll(items);
    return queue.iterator();
}
```

Comment: The Question is not clear, but seems to want to subgroup the objects first by duplicates of the `name` field. Then get an object with the maximum value of `quantity` field from that subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach filter items that have a quantity equal to the global maximum. But you want the maximum quantity for each item name right? So you should do something like the following.

```
List<Item> maxQuantityItems = itemList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .map(items -> items.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Item::getQuantity)).orElse(null))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```